# Rename files in multiple directories

Tags: python, rename

I have files named the same in multiple directories. I wanted to change their names, so they would correspond to the unique id of the directory that they are in.

'*' represents unique identifier, like '067' for example

The filename is always 'NoAdapter_len25.truncated_sorted.fastq'

I wanted the filename in each directory to be '*NoAdapter_len25.truncated_sorted.fastq', where * stands for the unique identifier

Here is the the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "change_names.py", line 19, in <module>
    rename(name, new_name)
TypeError: Can't convert '_io.TextIOWrapper' object to str implicitly
```

Here's the code that produces it:

```
from glob import glob
import re
from os import rename

#path = "/home/users/screening/results_Sample_*_hg38_hg19/N*"

files = glob(path)


for f in files:
    with open(f) as name:
        sample_id = f.partition('results_')[-1].rpartition('hg38_hg19')[0]
        #print(sample_id)
        back = f[-38:]
        new_name = sample_id + back
        rename(name, new_name)
```

Comment: and this error is...?

Comment: Why do you use parentheses around f[-38:]?

Comment: at the top of code section

Comment: I used f[-38:] to extract only the filename. Normally when I use print(f) it prints the whole path to the file

Comment: I see that, but why surround it with parentheses? i.e. why not `back = f[-38:]` ?

Comment: ok, that's a typo, I was probably printing it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. You're opening a file for no apparent reason (it confirms the file exists and is readable at `open` time, but even with an open handle, the name could be moved or deleted between that and the `rename`, so you aren't preventing any race conditions)
2. You're passing the opened file object to `os.rename`, but `os.rename` takes `str`, not file-like objects
3. You're doing a lot of "magic" manipulations of the path, instead of using appropriate `os.path` functions

Try this to simplify the code. I included some inline comments when I'm doing what your example does, but it doesn't make a lot of sense (or it's poor form):

```
for path in files:  # path, not f; f is usually placeholder for file-like object
    filedir, filename = os.path.split(path)
    parentdir = os.path.dirname(filedir)
    # Strip parentdir name to get 'Sample_*_' per provided code; is this what you wanted?
    # Question text seems like you only wanted the '*' part.
    sample_id = parentdir.replace('results_', '').replace('hg38_hg19', '')
    # Large magic numbers are code smell; if the name is a fixed name,
    # just use it directly as a string literal
    # If the name should be "whatever the file is named", use filename unsliced
    # If you absolutely need a fixed length (to allow reruns or something)
    # you might do keepnamelen = len('NoAdapter_len25.truncated_sorted.fastq')
    # outside the loop, and do f[-keepnamelen:] inside the loop so it's not
    # just a largish magic number
    back = filename[-38:]
    new_name = sample_id + back
    new_path = os.path.join(filedir, new_name)
    rename(path, new_path)
```

Answer (score -1):

You feed rename a file (`name`) and a filename, it needs two filenames. To get from a file to its filename, you can do this

```
old_filename = os.path.abspath(name.name)
```

Comment: @redaktroll, I changed my answer

Comment: Umm... `os.path.basename` is a function, not a string. Did you mean to call it on something? Regardless, it doesn't make sense; the `basename` is the file name without path, and you'd be `join`ing it to another name (that may or may not include a path). It's nonsensical.

Comment: @ShadowRanger sorry, corrected. I confused it with the current directory.

Comment: That's still not necessary and unrelated to the problem; if the file was opened with the given name (and no `os.chdir` has occurred), then it's valid (either absolute or relative doesn't matter). If anything, you'd need to pull its `dirname` and `join` it to the calculated `new_name`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `import this ... Explicit is better than implicit...` :-)

Comment: Explicitly converting to an absolute path when you already have a known working path (you _just_ opened it) is just wasting time twiddling your thumbs; it would be like changing every use of `a + b` to `int(x) + int(b)`, even when `a` and `b` are known to be integers; it's not wrong, but it's making things more complex and slower than they need to be (as long as we're quoting the zen, "Simple is better than complex".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94956/discussion-between-wardc-and-shadowranger).